# Enemy follow player when player is not looking. OnBecameInvisible not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I want to create a weeping angels effect on my enemies in my game. So when the player can see the enemy, they don't move and when the player can't see them, they move closer to the player. This is my code thats attached to the enemy and its not working. Would really appreciate some help!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class WeepingAngel : MonoBehaviour
{ 
     public GameObject Player;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
}
 void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    if (Player)
    {
        transform.position = Player.transform.position - Player.transform.forward;
        Vector3 lookPos = Player.transform.position - transform.position;
        lookPos.y = 0;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
    }    
}
}
```

Comment: What does `not working` mean exactly? Have you [debugged](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) and checked if `Player` is assigned at all? Is `OnBecameInvisible` called at all? And what exactly is your scene setup and situation when you expect that message to be called? Be aware that it means that this object is not contributing **at all** to the rendering of the scene .. as soon as e.g. any shadow is still visible then this message still won't be invoked !

Comment: well the enemy is supposed to follow the player when the player is not looking at the enemy and its not doing that

Comment: Well I got this from your description .. but now please read and answer the rest of the comment ^^

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, i just have an enemy idle in a building, and i want them to follow the player

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume that the `OnBecameInvisible` doesn't get called in situations where you think it should. The reason why that may happen is because it will react to ANY camera. That includes even the scene view.

### Alternative solution

Instead of `OnBecameInvisible` you can use the method available in this wiki article:
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=IsVisibleFrom

### Modified version of your code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class WeepingAngel : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    private new Camera camera;
    private new Renderer renderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        camera = Camera.main;
        renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        bool isVisible = GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(
            GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(camera),
            renderer.bounds);

        if (!isVisible)
            TryMovingTowardsPlayer();
    }

    private void TryMovingTowardsPlayer()
    {
        if (player == null)
            return;

        transform.position = player.transform.position - player.transform.forward;
        Vector3 lookPos = player.transform.position - transform.position;
        lookPos.y = 0;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which renderer should i attach to the gameobject?

Comment: @user12719872 Depends on your use case. If you have a 2D game, then `SpriteRenderer` would be the one that you would need I would assume. It inherits the `Renderer` class.